# 2020: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we welcome 2021, and in keeping with tradition, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU1Al.jpg). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Gardening & Landscaping over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 7 | 6 |
| Users destroyed³ | 12 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 3 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 9 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 175 | 64 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 6 | 1 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 162 | 16 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 242 | 57 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 1,021 | 473 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 9 | 1 |
| Revisions redacted | 2 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 8 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 0 | 26 |
| Questions migrated | 3 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 5 | 29 |
| Questions closed | 65 | 0 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 27 | 7 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 1 |
| Posts undeleted | 5 | 10 |
| Posts locked | 0 | 37 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 455 | 262 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 1,394 |
| Comments undeleted | 7 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 12 | 17 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 285 | 299 |
| Comment flags handled | 26 | 3 |
| Answers flagged | 96 | 400 |
| Answer flags handled | 470 | 26 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2019: a year in moderation](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/208518)

A big thank you to [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) for writing the queries and script to facilitate fetching and posting this data to all the sites in the network, and to [Brian](https://stackexchange.com/users/459488/brian-nickel) for the subsequent work making the whole thing more user friendly.

Wishing everyone a happy 2021!

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting but hard to evaluate without context. Specifically in percentage ratios by year for

- total questions deleted/total questions
- total answers deleted/total answers

and so on.

A comparison to other sites with a similar number of users would also be interesting if you are willing to assume that user behavior is the same regardless of topic

Comment: You should be able to get the data you need by crossing the data here with the data on [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/208518), which has data for all of the network sites.